# JSON.parse error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1)

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

```
    $.getJSON(staticMS, function(data) {
        stockData = data.products_and_categories;
        console.log(stockData);
        var typeData = JSON.parse(stockData)
        console.log(typeData.itemType);
    });
```

Not sure whats wrong with this, I keep getting a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" error. Trying to access part (itemType is specific earlier in the script) under the products_and_categories part of JSON file.

Tables under products and categories (after i click on 'object' in console):

Accessories: (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Hats: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Shirts: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Pants: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Comment: ```stockData``` is not a valid JSON string.

Comment: Please share what ```console.log(stockData);``` this line shows on console.

Comment: How should I fix it then? Or how could I access another table under stockData.

Comment: added what it shows in console, (i had to click on 'object' to get that)

Comment: I don't see anything like ```products_and_categories``` inside the ```data``` object. What I see is there is something valid like ```data.Accessories```

Comment: I think you can get the ```itemType``` by using something like this- ```data.Accessories[0]. itemType```

Comment: The original JSON data was bigger than that but I did data.products_and_categories to get that specific table (the one I posted is the products_and_categories table), now I'm trying to use what the user inputted to get another array (hats, accessories, etc) in the accessories_and_categories table which I set to stockData. If I do stockData.Hats, it works but if the user inputs (which is saved to localStorage as itemType) Hats, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

As Sajeeb commented, "`stockData` is not a valid JSON string." In fact, `stockData` is likely a JS object because

1) it's a field on parsed JSON, and JSON doesn't usually contain nested JSON

2) `JSON.parse` casts it's param to a string. A JS object stringified is `'[object Object]'`. Parsing this would produce the error you saw, 'Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1'.

If my assumption is right, then all you need to do is remove the nested `JSON.parse`:

```
  $.getJSON(staticMS, function(data) {
        stockData = data.products_and_categories;
        console.log(stockData);
        var typeData = stockData;
        console.log(typeData.itemType);
    });
```

Comment: When I do that I end up getting an undefined in console.

Comment: Perhaps there is no `itemType` property in `typeData`.
Looking at your question, it looks like the keys in your object are 'hats', 'accessories' etc. If you logged `stockData.hats` or `typeData.hats` you'd get an array

Comment: when I do .Hats it works but when i use .getItemType or .itemType (not sure what to use), I get undefined, so at the top of my file I have `var itemType = "itemType";` then in another onclick function I have `var item_type = document.getElementById('item_type').value;` and `getItemType = localStorage.getItem(itemType);` (after I set item_type to itemType), not sure what I'm doing wrong. (The other onclick function works and when I do `console.log(getItemType)` in this function, it works too)